# Toshiba Satellite plugged in not charging

Tags: windows, windows-vista, battery, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba Satellite that has vista installed on it. It's 3 years old and the battery lately hasn't been working very well. Recently though, I've had a problem of the battery indicator saying "plugged in not charging". I've taken out the battery and reinstalled the Microsoft ACPI-Compliant battery device. What should I do?

Comment: Does your laptop battery charge even though it says that it is not charging? Try removing your battery, and attaching the adapter and see if you can power the laptop. It looks like a problem with the power jack, adapter, power cable or the power plug. Check the cable for cuts. See if you can borrow an adapter (of the same kind) and try powering your laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on its size, use pattern and the type of battery, 3 years is not a small age. It is possible that this battery is indeed at the end of its useful lifecycle.

This is probably not the answer you want to hear, but it's time to buy a new battery.